# How to configure recaptcha javascript for proxy?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have one website url say `<http://example.com/somepathinfo>`.

We can access this url via a proxy url say `<http://myproxy.com/somepathinfo>`. In this page the recaptcha is not appearing. We have configured recaptcha using javascript API as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/js/recaptcha_ajax.js"></script>
```

Can anybody suggest a way to make it work?

Comment: as follows? has OP forgot do copy-paste?

Comment: Hello! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: As I mentioned in my earlier post that the url http://example.com/somepathinfo  opens a page which contains a form. In that form a recaptcha field is used. The captcha image is displayed properly when i open the http://example.com/somepathinfo . But when I open this url through proxy say http://myproxy.com?url=http://example.com/somepathinfo , this takes me to the page http://myproxy.com/somepathinfo. This page is same as http://example.com/somepathinfo . But here the captcha image is not apearing at all .

Comment: I am facing the problem while accessing the url ' http://example.com/somepathinfo' via ezproxy as follows  'http://myproxy.com?url=http://example.com/somepathinfo' .  Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: Do you mean that you are using a **web proxy**? If that is the case, I imagine that the problem may be that javascript is disabled on that proxy you are using.